# unable to access meteor mongodb running on vm from the host using the ip address

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have meteor app runnong on a ubuntu vm with windows host machine. from the windows machine i am trying to connect to meteor db with pymongo python client but the connection fails because target machine actively refuses it.

i use the ubuntu machines ip address for accessing the db like

```
pymongo.Connection(host='192.168.1.118',port=3002)
```

But i am able to access the meteor app from the windows machine with the ubuntu ip address like

```
http://192.168.1.118:3000
```

This works perfectly fine. Is there any thing with the meteor mongo db which is rejecting all the connections anything other than local host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In meteor the mongo database is locally bound to the ip address `127.0.0.1` so `192.168.1.118` will not work. At least this is the behavior I observe on mine.

You have to proxy the connection via SSH (socks) or enable the database to accessed anywhere. Putty may be able to do this but I'm a bit unsure on how to do it on windows. On *nix the `-D` param is used while connecting to it to create the proxy.

Sometimes it can work if you create an iptables rule for port 3002 and disable selinux but i'm not sure this will be helpful.

There isn't much of a way around it as it's hard coded into meteor. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/8de5ebfc6fda4865a13b6dbc3367a761ed98baed/tools/mongo_runner.js#L204

You would have to fork meteor and alter that line to bind to 0.0.0.0 (all ips) to let it be accessed from outside

Another option would be to run your own mongodb with your own config that allows all IPs to connect to it and set `MONGO_URL` as the environmental variable when you run your project to that mongo instance instead of letting meteor spawn its own.

Comment: Akshat, I didn't see any workaround for my problem so finally deciced to go with MONGO_URL to connect to the mongodb server running on my windows machine. Now i am able to connect to the mongodb and update.